# Accessing Workflow History List

Tags: list, workflow

Is there an easy way to access History list, than to type URL?

Comment: From SPD or VS?  You need more detail in your question.  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean if there is an easy way to navigate to the Default View for the History List, using the browser?

I believe the History List is a hidden list, so I don't expect you to find any hyperlinks pointing to it.

You could add the link yourself (i.e. add to quicklaunch), either through the UI or create a Feature if you want a more global and reusable solution.

Comment: Got you...guess using a feature  to add it in quicklaunch should do. I was just thinking if I can reach it somehow through UI.

Thanks Anyways.

Comment: As far as I know you should be able to add your own links to the quick launch through the UI, but if you want to have this link on all sites in a site collection you would probably want to automate the process of adding the link.

Comment: The URL to get to that list is: 
https://<yoursite>Lists/Workflow%20History/AllItems.aspx

See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The Workflow history list is hidden.
But that doesn't mean you can't browse to it if you know the URL.

```
https://<yoursite>Lists/Workflow%20History/AllItems.aspx
```

Will give you access.

You can also unhide the list temporarily with Powershell:

```
 $web = get-spweb  https://<sharepointsitename>
 $web.Lists["Workflow History"]
 $wfhistory = $web.Lists["Workflow History"]
 $wfhistory.Hidden = $false
 $wfhistory.update()
```

Then you can see the workflow history under View All Site Content at https:///_layouts/viewlsts.aspx

After you are done:

```
$wfhistory.Hidden = $true
$wfhistory.update()
$web.dispose
```